# Mongodb Connections

Tags: mongodb

I am facing Mongodb Connection isuue. I have a server running on production with mongodb connection and after 5-6 days, the apis can't connect to mongodb. Please Help.

`mongo.connect(url,{poolSize: 10,autoReconnect:true,keepAlive:30000,connectTimeoutMS:30000,socketTimeoutMS:360000,reconnectTries:100,reconnectInterval:10000})`